# Equivalent of CakePHP HttpSocket in Guzzle

Tags: php, cakephp, guzzle

I have a piece of code which written in CakePHP for sending a `HTTP Post Request` to a URI and get response.

I don't know CakePHP and need to change that to [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) style for sending that `HTTP Post Request`.

Here is the CakePHP code :

```
private static function sendRequest() {
        App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
        try {
            $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
            return trim($HttpSocket->post(self::$webserviceUri, self::$requestData, [
                'header' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml'],
                'auth' => ['method' => 'Basic', 'user' => self::$username, 'pass' => self::$password]
            ]));
        } catch (SocketException $e) {
            CakeLog::write('request_error', 'Request Error: '. $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**The Main Goal Is:**

How can I send exactly a such HTTP Post Request( above code ) by using Guzzle?

Any helps would be great appreciated.

*P.S:
I'm using Guzzle 6.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$client = new Client(['auth' => ['username', 'password'], 'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml']]);
$client->request('POST', self::$webserviceUri, ['body' => self::$requestData]);
```

I believe it should work, I haven't tested it out but the idea is this one.

Comment: `self::$requestData` is not json! it's in xml type.

Comment: @HamedKamrava sorry, my bad, maybe this one will work for you, I've edited the code.

Comment: Worked Like a charm. Thank You